# c programming - printing sequence of sum of squared digits (as an array) for a potential happy number

Tags: c, arrays, printing, numbers

I have this assignment for my intro to C programming class and part of my code has to find the sequence of the sum of square digits of a number in order to determine after if the given number is a happy number (sum of square digits = 1)

Here's part of my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
```

// The sum of square digits function

```
int sqd (int x) {

int sum = 0;

while (x > 0) {

    sum = sum + pow(x%10, 2);
    x = x/10;
}
return sum;
}
```

// The search function

```
int search (int a[], int val, int size) {

    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        if (a[i] == val) {
            return 1;
        }
    }

   return 0;
}
```

// The main program

```
void main () {

    int a [1000] = {0};
    int N;
    int count = 1;
    int j;

    printf("Please enter the potential happy number:\n", N);

    scanf ("%d", &N);

    a[0] = N;
    a[count] = sqd (N); 

    do {    
        a[count] = sqd (a[count-1]);
        count++;
    } while (search (a, a[count], count));

    for ( j = 0; j <= count; j++) {  
        printf("%d\n", a[j]);
    }
}
```

It only prints the first three sums in the sequence. I really don't know how to make it work.

Thank you in advance

Comment: sorry, there's an extra "}" before while

Comment: You can always edit your question.

Answer (score 1):

This line

```
while (search (a, a[count], count));
```

makes sure that you break out of the loop after one round since `a[1]` is not equal to`a[0]`. You can change that line to be:

```
while (a[count-1] != 1);
```

You also need to add a clause to make sure that you stop when the limit of the array is reached. Update that line to be:

```
while (a[count-1] != 1 && count < 1000 );
```

And then, change the printing loop to use `i < count`, not `i <= count`. Using `<=` will result in accessing the array out of bounds when the user enters a sad number.

```
for ( j = 0; j < count; j++){  

   printf("%d\n", a[j]);
}
```

**Update**

After a bit of reading on happy numbers at Wikipedia, I understand why you had call to `search` in the conditional of the `while`. The following also works.

```
} while ( ! (a[count-1] == 1 || search(a, a[count-1], count-1)) );
```

That will search for the last number in the array but only up to the previous index.